# C - Minimum Power of 2 Algorithm - Looking for Help to Understand Calc

Tags: c

I'm just trying to understand how this minimum power of 2 algorithm works, in particular, how this piece of code, result *= 2, returns the minimum power of 2 from the number entered by the user.  I cannot seem to figure it out, even when I write it out manually.  Any help to clarify would be greatly appreciated!

```
int main()
{

int userInput, result;

do
{
  printf("Enter a number (-1 to exit): ");
  scanf("%d", &userInput);

  if (userInput > 0)
  {
    result = 1;
    while (result < userInput)
    {
       result *= 2;
    }
    printf("Minimum power of 2 greater than %d: %d\n", userInput, result);
  }

} while (userInput != -1);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output when 3 is entered: Min.....3: 4
Output when 5 is entered: Min.....5: 8

Comment: This code is very simple and therefore you should be able to figure it out with a pencil and a piece of paper.

Comment: Add this statement right before the `result *= 2` statement. `printf("result is currently %d and is getting raised to %d\n", result, result*2);`  Then run your code again with different inputs.  It should make the algorithm more recognizable. Even after many years of coding, I still find it useful to add "debug print statements" so I can see how code works. It's the most basic debugging tool.

Comment: Since `result` multiplies by 2 every iteration, it is always a power of two.  The loop stops once that power of two is greater than or equal to `userInput`.

Comment: This is a good opportunity to use your debugger - you can step through the code and observe the values of `result` and `userInput` at each step.

Answer (score 1):

There are no problems with the implementation of this algorithm<sup>[1]</sup>. This algorithm returns the least power of 2, provided it is greater than or equal to the variable `userInput`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int userInput, result;

    do{
        printf("Enter a number (-1 to exit): ");
        scanf("%d", &userInput);
    
        if (userInput > 0){
            result = 1;
            int counter = 0;
            
            while (result < userInput){
                result *= 2;
                printf("Result: %d\t Counter: %d\n", result, counter++);
            }
        
            printf("Result: %d ^ %d = %d\n", 2, counter, (int) pow(2, counter));
            printf("Minimum power of 2 greater than %d: %d\n", userInput, result);
        }
    
    } while (userInput != -1);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In the above application, if the user enters the value 11, the following result is produced:

```
Enter a number (-1 to exit): 11
Result: 2       Counter: 0
Result: 4       Counter: 1
Result: 8       Counter: 2
Result: 16      Counter: 3
Result: 2 ^ 4 = 16
Minimum power of 2 greater than 11: 16
```

---

<sup>1 - [Smallest power of 2 greater than or equal to n](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-power-of-2-greater-than-or-equal-to-n/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
while (result < userInput)
{
   printf("Before: %d\n");
   result *= 2;
   printf("After: %d\n\n");
}
```

And you'll see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
    result = 1;
    while (result < userInput)
    {
       result *= 2;
    }
...
```

Every time `result` is tested and it's lesser than `userInput`, `result` is doubled.
In the case of `5` as `userInput`

| iterations | `result` | `userInput` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| at start | 1 | 5 (>`result` so continue looping) |
| iteration 1 | 2 | 5 (>`result` so continue looping) |
| iteration 2 | 4 | 5 (>`result` so continue looping) |
| iteration 3 | 8 | 5 (<`result` so loop stops) |